# String To Double Error With Switch-Case Calculator

Tags: c#

Basically, the program calculates the two numbers we enter, according to the entered sign.

[image: Program Picture]

But I got an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

To be honest I don't have any idea about this. I'm still learning the language. Need help about this.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2;
    string sembol;
    double rslt;
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    sembol = textBox3.Text;
    rslt = textBox4.ToString();
    
    switch (sembol)
    {
        case "+": rslt = num1 + num2; break;
        case "-": rslt = num1 - num2; break;
        case "*": rslt = num1 * num2; break;
        case "/": rslt = num1 / num2; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" will guide you in the right direction?

Comment: `TextBox4.ToString()` is returning a string value that you need to convert to the appropriate numeric type =) but why ToString for box4 but .Text for all others? I think you mean to have that assignment the other way around, after the calculation, no? TextBox4.Text = rslt.ToString()

Comment: @MathieuGuindon exactly! But it says unassigned variable while i trying  "TextBox4.Text = rslt.ToString()". But the result things already coming from switch-case thing, how can i assign something to it?

Comment: If the box is empty or no case otherwise applies, the value remains unassigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This row is causing the trouble:

```
rslt = textBox4.ToString();
```

You're trying to read an string containing object information into a double, that won't work.

Just skip this line. Then add this:

```
textBox4.Text = rslt.ToString();
```

to your code after the switch-Statement.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1, num2;
    string sembol;
    double rslt;
    //num1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    //num2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    // This will try to read the input and make sure that no exception is thrown due to non numeric input
    if(!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num1) || !int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out num2))
    {
       textBox4.Text = "INVALID INPUT";
       return;
    }
    sembol = textBox3.Text;
    
    switch (sembol)
    {
        case "+": rslt = num1 + num2; break;
        case "-": rslt = num1 - num2; break;
        case "*": rslt = num1 * num2; break;
        case "/": 
           // Check second value to prevent a divsion by zero
           if(num2 == 0)
           {
               textBox4.Text = "INVALID INPUT";
               return;
           }
           else
           {
               rslt = num1 / num2;
           }
           break;
        // This will handle anything that doesn't represent a valid operation
        default:
            textBox4.Text = "INVALID INPUT";
            return;
    }
    // Having checked every input for invalid characters, you can be sure rslt is properly set
    textBox4.Text = rslt.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `rslt` isn't definitely assigned in the last line...

Comment: You mean, If someone puts something invalid into the textboxes? That's a good point, but makes things a bit more complicated. I'll edit the answer to solve it.

Comment: Yes i did this exactly but its still saying "unassigned value" for "rslt". But isnt it already coming from switch-case?  Also still giving same "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string' " error after updated it. @kinda-wired

Comment: Added checks.
Try to set breakpoints in order to see what statements are hit and which are not.

Comment: Thanks for update it, more explainable now!

Comment: I added another check in the "/" case to prevent a division by 0 error.